# Wireless devices on same network cannot reach each other

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a LinkSys E1200, running Tomato 1.28 (Shibby). Until recently, I had apparently never tried to connect from one wireless device to another. Now that I try to SSH (into a raspberry pi zero) from a laptop on the same wi-fi network, I find that neither device can see the other. `ping` from either end announces it's going to ping to (and from) the expected IP addresses, but no packets get through (`Destination Host Unreachable`).

I *can* SSH from one to a wired host on the same network and then from there reach the other, but that's obviously inconvenient and certainly wasn't necessary with this router's predecessor, a WRT54GL.

What should I be looking for as a cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*AP Isolation* in *Advanced Wireless Settings*:

> This isolates all wireless clients and wireless devices on your network from each other. Wireless devices will be able to communicate with the Gateway but not with each other in the network.

<sup>([source](http://tomatousb.org/settings:wireless#toc1))</sup>

Comment: That certainly describes the behaviour, but it was already set to `disabled`. After a reboot of the router, the behaviour and the setting now match.